# Percentile calculation in HIVE

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, percentile

How can I calculate 25 percentile in Hive using sql. Let's say there is category, sub category and sales column. So how can I calculate the 25 percentile of sales? I tried to use the `percentile(sales, 0.25)` in hive but it is throwing an error:

> Error while compiling statement: FAILED: NoMatchingMethodException No matching method for class org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDAFPercentile with (double, decimal(2,2)). Possible choices: *FUNC*(bigint, array) *FUNC*(bigint, double)

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results, so we know what YOU mean by "calculate 25 percentile".

Answer (score 3):

[Documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-Built-inAggregateFunctions(UDAF)) says:

> A true percentile can only be computed for integer values. Use
>   PERCENTILE_APPROX if your input is non-integral.

Use `percentile_approx` for non-integral values.  `percentile_approx(DOUBLE col, p [, B])` - Returns an approximate pth percentile of a numeric column (including floating point types) in the group. The B parameter controls approximation accuracy at the cost of memory. Higher values yield better approximations, and the default is 10,000. When the number of distinct values in col is smaller than B, this gives an exact percentile value.